# How to Change my Select SQL to Update SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have managed to write the following SQL that gives me all records that have the same value in _price, _regular_price & _sale_price.

I need to update _sale_price on these records only to ' ' (nothing / empty)

Here is my working Select:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p1.meta_key, p1.meta_value, p2.meta_key, p2.meta_value, p3.meta_key, p3.meta_value
FROM sm_posts p

INNER JOIN sm_postmeta p1 ON p.id = p1.post_id
AND p1.meta_key = '_price'

INNER JOIN sm_postmeta p2 ON p.id = p2.post_id
AND p2.meta_key = '_regular_price'

INNER JOIN sm_postmeta p3 ON p.id = p3.post_id
AND p3.meta_key = '_sale_price'

WHERE p1.meta_value = p2.meta_value AND p1.meta_value = p3.meta_value
```

I need to create an Update from this but cant figure it out.

So far I have this but its not working:

```
UPDATE sm_postmeta2,
(
    SELECT p.id, p.post_title, p1.meta_key, p1.meta_value, p2.meta_key, p2.meta_value, p3.meta_key, p3.meta_value
    FROM sm_posts p
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p1 ON p.id = p1.post_id
    AND p1.meta_key = '_price'
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p2 ON p.id = p2.post_id
    AND p2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p3 ON p.id = p3.post_id
    AND p3.meta_key = '_sale_price'
    WHERE p1.meta_value = p2.meta_value AND p1.meta_value = p3.meta_value
GROUP BY  p1.ID
) 
SET sm_postmeta2.meta_value = ''
WHERE sm_postmeta2.meta_value.id = p1.id
```

Please can someone help, i am new to SQL and it took me forever just to get the joins working. lol

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You should simply be able to `UPDATE` and `SET` instead of `SELECT`; your joins and conditions should work on an `UPDATE`. Does this not work?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I cant figure out how to structure it, everything i try throws sql errors

Comment: can you post an example of what you've tried?

Comment: and what's not working? are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes getting an error : 1 Every derived table must have its own alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that you must alias the subquery. However, you don't want to put the subquery in the `UPDATE` clause. If you do, MySQL either won't allow it, or it will update the temporary table resulting from the subquery, i.e. the changes wouldn't persist. Instead, you can `INNER JOIN` on the subquery to get the rows you want to update.

Since you're just using the subquery to determine the rows to update, you don't need to `SELECT` all the same values as before. Instead, you can just `SELECT` the primary key for the records you want to update.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE sm_postmeta2 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT p3.meta_id
    FROM sm_posts p
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p1 ON p.id = p1.post_id
    AND p1.meta_key = '_price'
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p2 ON p.id = p2.post_id
    AND p2.meta_key = '_regular_price'
    INNER JOIN sm_postmeta2 p3 ON p.id = p3.post_id
    AND p3.meta_key = '_sale_price'
    WHERE p1.meta_value = p2.meta_value AND p1.meta_value = p3.meta_value
) p_tmp ON sm_postmeta2.meta_id = p_tmp.meta_id
SET sm_postmeta2.meta_value = ''
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I see I was completely off the mark, I will try work on from your example, I did try it as is but got:  #1054 - Unknown column 'p3.id' in 'field list'

Comment: After a small tweak I got is to run without error but it sets all 3 ( _price, _regular_price & _sale_price) to ' ' I need it to only set ' ' for _sale_price to ' '.

Comment: The primary key on postmeta2 is: meta_id and the Primary Key on sm_posts is ID.

Comment: @Wozzy updated my answer with this key instead of `id`, which I used before

Comment: Thanks so much for all the effort, I have tried numerous variations within my limited ability - lol  but unfortunately its now not replacing anything in the _sale_price - 0 rows affected (47669 total, Query took 0.2258 sec)

Comment: I Got it working !! Thank you very much your a legend !